# How to use GetKeyDown() to efficiently detect when any key is being released

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, keycode

I will begin by saying that I'm very new to C# and Unity, so apologies in advance if I am lacking what would be considered common knowledge. Also, I have checked other questions on here and have not found any answers that particularly solved my specific issue. If there is one however, I would appreciate being pointed towards it.

Anyway, I am trying to write some code that will play a sound when a key is held down and will stop playing when the key is released. Different keys will play different sounds, so the GetKeyUp() function should apply to whatever key is currently being pressed.

I have declared a string for inputKey, and inputKey is assigned whatever key is being pressed, and is then passed through to an if statement containing the GetKeyUp() function. I have tried numerous small variations of this method but the one I am currently using has been the only way that hasn't yielded an error message (although the code still doesn't work)

```
public string inputKey;

else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
    {
        freq = 293.66;
        gain = volume;
    }

inputKey = (Input.inputString).ToUpper();

if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.inputKey));
    {
        gain = 0;
    }
```

So in the example above, when the key S is pressed, the sound is played. The inputKey is being displayed as 'S' so I would expect 'Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.inputKey)' to be the equivalent of 'Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.S' and the sound to stop playing, yet this is not the case and the sound continues to play.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## I would use [`Input.GetKey()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKey.html) instead.

Rather than checking "is `S` down? start playing the S sound. Is `A` down? start playing the A sound. Did any key get released? What key was it? stop playing that sound" I would simply check each key's *current state* and start or stop the sound based on that state.

E.g.

```
soundOnS.gain = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) ? volume : 0;
```

Your current approach can not, and never could, adequately handle what happens if someone presses down on multiple keys at the same time: when they lift up one finger, releasing one key (but not the other!) what sound should be playing?

Comment: Hi, what you've suggested sounds good, although I haven't quite been able to get it to work for me. Would you be able to explain what each part of your suggested code is doing?

Comment: I've been trying something along the lines of          
 else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.J) ? gain : 0)
        {
            freq = 493.88;
            gain = volume;
        }                                                                                    but I keep getting the error message about not being able to explicitly convert a float to a boolean. Thanks

Comment: I've done a bit more experimenting. Within the 'void update()' function, I included 'gain = 0;' and then used: 'else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.J))
        {
            freq = 493.88;
            gain = volume;
        }       ' This works as I wanted to but now when the note is played there are audible clicks at random intervals. I assume that this is because the 'gain = 0;' is being reread and so the volume of the note is bouncing around. Is this correct? And if so how would I be able to fix this? Thanks

Comment: @tewi I have no idea how your `freq` and `gain` variables are being used later on in the program. In either case, the issue you're having is probably due to what you suspect, which is why I suggest using the [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation) instead of setting gain to 0 then resetting it to another value based on an if-block.

Comment: Hi, you're right - I should have been more clear about my variables and their purposes. freq(frequency) is just a number in hertz of an audio wave, essentially just controlling the pitch of the sound. Gain is a sort of individual volume control for each sound, with the volume variable itself remaining constant across every sound. I have now made a function that gets the desired result using an if statement to set the frequency of the wave and separately the suggested ternary operation to control the gain variable.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and suggestions, and sorry for any confusion!! :)